# Update MS access table using VBA recordset with 2/more inner join sub statements

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, recordset

I have 3 tables in access - tblUsers, tblAssignnent and tblJob. The tblJob is where using a series of calculations in VBA, I arrive at the data dump which is to be worked by my Quality (QC) team. The tblUsers has a list of all our staff and where they are located globally. The tblAssignnent defines which QC team analyst will work on which case processed by our staff globally. For eg. QCID 123 needs to work on all Level 3 cases worked by our staff in China. Accordingly, VBA must allocate QCID 123 to all those rows where individuals in China have worked at Level 3. We have about 20 such QC IDs and an average of 1000 cases worked daily.

Again, the catch here is that tblUsers defines the name and location of each staff - tblAssignnent defines location and level of each staff along with QC ID expected to work. The tblJob has the Name of staff and Level. Check out he shapshot below,

```
tblUsers
NAME        LOCATION    
Mathew      Shanghai
John        New York
Peter       Dubai

tblAssignnent
QCID        LEVEL       LOCATION
123         L3          Shanghai
135         L1          New York

tblJob
QCID        LEVEL       NAME        CASEID
            L3          Mathew      001283526
            L1          John        827271729
```

So basically I need QCID to be updated with 123 and 135 in tblJob using VBA. I attempted INNER JOIN within a recordset but I kept getting errors. On search, apparently a VBA recordset may not be able to hold complex statements. Forgive me for my poor formatting as I only have access to my phone now. All my attempts at this code has failed and I will be much obliged for any help extended.

I remain at your disposal for further clarification.

Comment: It's not clear what do you mean under *I need QCID to be updated*. You have an option to automatically update `tblJob` table when `QCID` in `tblAssignnent` changes its value. In order for it to work, you must define `QCID` and `Level` as primary keys (this means that one `QCID` can have several `Level`s) in both `tblJob` an `tblAssignnent` tables. Then cascading updating will do the update automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your response JohnyL. When tblJob is generated, the QCID column is blank. The front end user then has the capability to define what each QC team member is expected to perform using the tblAssignnent table. On a command button click event, I would expect the QCID column in tblAssignnent to be filled in based on the criteria given in tblAssignnent. I am quite unsure of how to use a SQL update query here which is why I resort to using a recordset loop within VBA. Would you be able to help define the query/code in this case?

Comment: ***tblAssignnent** to be filled in based on the criteria given in **tblAssignnent*** Did you misspell? :)

Comment: Ahh yes my bad. tblJob to be filled in based on the criteria given in tblAssignnent. Sorry JohnyL

Comment: I guess I understood your requirement: You want to assign `QCID` in `tblJob` table, which would be taken from `tblAssignment` table based on `LEVEL` column. Am I right? 

Comment: While this would be easy to do in a join, how do you account for the 1 to many on QC employees of the same location and same level?

Comment: My point in asking is I assume there are more than a few employees who need work allocated. This doesnt seem like a simple task when you incorporate the practical implementation. The worst thing that can happen is you have one employee doing all the work and others not getting allocated anything. I would assume if its only access sql (no sql sevrer back end) then you may have to do cheap hacks to randomly allocate (like vba sorting algorithms) or join on the users/assignments tbls and then selecting random records from another join.

Comment: And honestly since youre in access why dont you just develop a form that shows users CASEID's based on level? Then you wouldnt actually have to allocate work, they could just work out of the queue. Seems like a mor ehands off approach however I am not sure of the set up you have there either.

Comment: @JohnyL - Yes you're almost there. I need to assign QCID in tblJob table which would be taken from tblAssignnent table based on LEVEL and LOCATION. The LOCATION for each NAME is what is given in tblUsers. We have to incorporate 3 tables for this one which is the catch I have.

Comment: Considering only the data in examples, which seem overly simplistic, tblJob and tblAssignment could be combined to a single table. The following query works for the given data sample. If you get errors then the data is not accurately represented.

`UPDATE tblJob INNER JOIN (tblAssignment INNER JOIN tblUsers ON tblAssignment.Location = tblUsers.Location) ON (tblJob.EmpName = tblUsers.EmpName) AND (tblJob.Level = tblAssignment.Level) SET tblJob.QCID = [tblAssignment]![QCID];`

Comment: Huh... If you define QCID by LEVEL and LOCATION, then how to calculate location, since location is stored in Users table?

Comment: @Doug Coats - I see your fair argument. I intend to split the rows equally among those QCIDs that are assigned the same LEVEL and LOCATION. I have been successful with that using a recordset loop previously on a single criteria in the same table but with more variables like LEVEL and LOCATION coming in from different tables, I'm stuck and which is where I'd like your help. All this is performed purely on Access and is independent of the database on the server. You suggested using joins, would you be able to help me with that? I can steer that way if that's more viable an option

Comment: @JohnyL - that is pretty much the question I have for you sir! :) I pretty much have the entire database in my control so I can do walk arounds as I please. What do you suggest?

Comment: @June7 - this maybe what I am looking for but as a query. I was looking more along the lines of a VBA code but that doesn't really matter as long as the job is done. Allow me a bit to have this tested and return to you.

Comment: What I'm thinking is that is combination of LEVEL and LOCATION in tblAssignments unique? I mean, can it give several QCIDs?

Comment: @JohnyL - it need not be unique. For example, QCID 543 and 671 both may have to work on L2 cases processed by our staff in New York. So yes, several QCIDs can be assigned to the same criteria. In these cases, I would expect assignment to be done equally. That is how I picture it atleast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I maybe misread this earlier. If you only need the QCID added to the table Job its really simple :

```
UPDATE (tblJob 
INNER JOIN tblAssignment ON tblJob.LEVEL = tblAssignment.LEVEL) 
INNER JOIN tblUsers ON (tblUsers.Location = tblAssignment.Location) 
AND (tblJob.EName = tblUsers.EName) 
SET tblJob.QCID = tblAssignment.QCID
```

Comment: Hey Doug. Apologies for keeping this late. Thanks for getting me started with this piece of query above. I got it working with minor tweaks to your solution. Many thanks for your help! :)